# Need help writing recursive query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table in access with the following format:-

```
ID  |  Name  |  Qty
----+--------+------
  1 |  A1    |  10
  2 |  A2    |  20
  3 |  A1    |  30
  4 |  A2    |  40
  5 |  A1    |  50
----+--------+------
```

I want to run a query which will return the sum of Qty for each row above it where the Name matches. So, the Output will be :-

```
ID  |  Name  |  Output
----+--------+---------
  1 |  A1    |  0
  2 |  A2    |  0
  3 |  A1    |  10
  4 |  A2    |  20
  5 |  A1    |  40
----+--------+----------
```

I am not being able to write the query. I think I need some kind of recursive query, but I'm not very well versed in SQL/Databases.

Comment: should the output from `A1` not be 10+30+50 = 90 ? ( i don't see some logic from Qty to Output )

Comment: Hi, actually no, that would be a simple sum and group by combo. 
So, the logic can be written I think in this way -

**id-n**, **Output** = sum(Qty) for all **id** < **id-n**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access does not support recursion. The following query should do what you want (i called your table NameQty):

```
SELECT t1.Id,t1.name,sum(t2.Qty)
FROM NameQty t1
    LEFT JOIN NameQty t2 ON t1.name=t2.name AND t1.Id>t2.Id
GROUP BY t1.Id,t1.name
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

I think you should also use some other column than ID for the definition of "above".

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response. I will change the "above" definition into something more reliable. Thanks!

Comment: +1 It works. BTW, it will be nice if you get rid of the null values. Use Coalesce.